# Active Record Relation Method to aggregate associated has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Consider these two models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd like to do something like this but it will not work:

```
my_users        = User.where(age: 35) 
all_assoc_blogs = my_users.blogs # errors out
```

Here is the error:

> undefined method `blogs' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation:

I understand why it doesn't work: you can only call `blogs` on a single `user` object.  You cannot call `blogs` on an active record relation object of `users`.

Ultimately, I want an active record relation object which consists of an aggregate of all the blogs for all the users in the `my_users` active record relation object. Is there a slick rails way of doing this?  This is the only way I can think of and it is pretty ugly:

```
my_users   = User.where(age: 35)
temp_blogs = []
my_users.each {|u| temp_blogs << u.blogs.to_a}
blog_ids = temp_blogs.flatten.pluck(:id)
Blog.where(id: blog_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was looking for:

```
my_users = User.where(age: 35)
Blog.where(user: my_users)
```

What was tripping me up was that I had to switch gears.  I first grab the relevant `users`, but then I pass those `users` into a `Blog` query.

Since I ultimately want an active record relation of `blogs`, the cleanest way is to make sure the top model I start with in the query is `Blog`.

Answer (score 1):

Active record's where Metrodome returns you an active record relation, not an unique result. You need to:

```
my_users = User.where(age: 35).first
```

Then you should be able to get the blogs of one user with:

```
my_users.blogs
```

But if your intention is to have all the blogs of different users, you should try to:

```
my_user_ids = User.where(id: 35).pluck(:id)
Blog.where(user_id: my_user_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you:

```
Blog.joins(:user).where(user: User.where(age: :35))
```

or

```
Blog.joins(:user).merge(User.where(age: :35))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but you can do this more efficiently and reduce your database queries like so.

```
my_users = User.includes(:blogs).where(age: 35)  # this makes one db query to get all data
all_assoc_blogs = my_users.map(&:blogs)
```

Comment: This is certainly a valid point, but it does not return a `Blog` active record relation object. Instead: it returns an array.